# Adding events to a buttons array

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am creating some buttons dynamically in vb.net, but i am not able to create the click event handler.

This is my code:

```
dim b(10) 
dim x=0
b(x) = New Button
b(x).width = 100
b(x).height = 25
b(x).location = New Point(500, pos + 24)
b(x).visible = True
b(x).text = "Remove"

AddHandler b(x).Click, AddressOf remove_click
```

I am getting the following error when i try to compile
'Click' is not an event of 'Object'.

```
Public Sub remove_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
' onclick code
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you never provided a type for the local `b` hence it's defined as an array of `Object`.  The type `Object` has no Click event hence `AddHandler` fails.  You need to declare this as an array of `Button` values

```
dim b(10) as Button
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always assume the compiler is right, and then try to discover what that implies. It says 'Click' isn't an event of 'Object', so you must be referencing *object*.Click, which implies that `b(x)` is an object, which implies that `b` is an array of object.

You thought it was an array of `Button`.

So,

```
Dim b(10) As Button
```